# Micropython: Non-Blocking SSLSocket

Tags: sockets, ssl, micropython

I was just trying [SSL-Sockets](https://micropython.org/resources/docs/en/latest/wipy/library/ussl.html) in Micropython and discovered that I can not set the connection to non-blocking as the `setblocking()` function is not implemented, yet.

```
>>> import ussl
>>> import usocket
>>> s = usocket.socket()
>>> adr = usocket.getaddrinfo('myserverwithssl.com', 443)[0][-1]
>>> s.connect(adr)
>>> s_ssl = ussl.wrap_socket(adr)
>>> s_ssl.setblocking(False)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NotImplementedError:
```

Looking forward to the implementation. However, is there another way to achieve nonblocking SSL-Sockets in Micropython?

Comment: Never worked with _Micropython_, but shouldn't you call `setblocking` on `s` rather than `s_ssl`?

Comment: @CristiFati I tried this. It is not working. A `s_ssl.read()` will still block. Even on CPython you need to use the `setblocking` method of the SSLSocket object otherwise you will get a `ValueError:  do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets`

Comment: It seems this was recently merged: https://github.com/micropython/micropython/pull/3226

Comment: That's great news. I'll give it a try asap. Thanks for letting me know.